# smoke flow outwards from a source

Tags: smoke-simulation, force-fields

I'm trying to make a realistic rendition of the head of this character using a smoke simulation.

[image: reference image]

However I'm having a hard time getting the smoke to billow outwards from the face; it seems to only flow in a straight column whether using temperature difference or any of the wind settings. Should I crank up the strength of the turbulence field, or do you have some other ideas of how I might achieve this, another sort of force field maybe?

Here's my setup as it stands now:
[image: element positions and settings]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try using a particle system to control the smoke. If you add some normal velocity to the particles they will spread out form the head a lot more. Particles will still be affected by the force fields, but you will also have a number of other controls as well to control how they behave.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I completely understand, as far as I can see it a particle system would be an addition on top of the smoke. Are you suggesting recreatiing the default smoke as a particle system, letting you use the more advanced controls, or is there some other way of controlling the smoke with a particle system as you say?

Comment: At the top left of the screen shot you provided where the settings for the smoke flow object are, there is a menu where you can select mesh or particle system. Currently your object is set to emit smoke form the mesh. What you can do is add a particle system, make the particles behave in the way you want the smoke to, and then set the particle system to be the flow source. That way the particles will define where the smoke is, and thus you will have access to all of the particle settings as well to achieve the result you want.

Comment: Ohhh, I see, very interesting. That gives me a lot of things to play around with now, I might even be able to have multiple layers of smoke like in the reference by using multiple particle systems with different settings. Thanks!